# How better to test and create a new list, if it does not exist in List<List<T>> structure?

Tags: java, list, guava

How better to test and create a new list, if it does not exist?

I only found this solution:

```
private List<List<Action>> actionList = Lists.newArrayList();

...

f(int index){
    Optional<List<Action>> optionalActionList = Optional.fromNullable(actionList.get(index));
    if (!optionalActionList.isPresent()) {
        actionList.add(new ArrayList<Action>());
    }
    actionList.get(index).add(index, new Action());
}
```

Maybe I should change the structure of storage? (The order of addition. Ability to add both the beginning and the end of the list. Are important in both lists).
Can use Google Guava if need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what the `Optional` is really buying you here. I see the value of `Optional` as communicating between methods, or in storage.

Additionally, I don't think the code is doing what you think it is - you're asking for the list *at a particular index*, but then if the value at that index is null, you're adding a new list *at the end*. It sounds like you want:

```
f(int index){
    List<Action> list = actionList.get(index);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<Action>();
        actionList.set(index, list);
    }
    // Note: no need to use index at all here... potentially
    list.add(new Action());
}
```

Note that I'm *not* using `add(index, new Action())` at the end - at it was very unclear why you'd want to do so. You've already got to the right list using `index` - why would you use `index` *again*?

The above assumes that the "outer" list is already the right size, but filled with nulls for "absent" lists. If that's not the case, you'll need to detect when `index` is beyond the bounds of the current outer list.

Basically, if the above doesn't help, please give more information as your question is currently unclear.

Comment: Thx for answer. Yes, not need index in .add. It is my mistake. I thought Guava provides methods to do this.

Comment: @K.G.V.: Well Guava provides `MultiSet`, `MultiMap` and `Table`, any of which *may* be useful to you. I can't think of anything else *offhand* which would help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not on Java 7 instead of

```
list = new ArrayList<Action>();
```

you can use

```
list = Lists.newArrayList();
```

if you add a static import to this you can shorten it to

```
list = newArrayList();
```